# Find Average of Rows Using Pipe Function in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to find the average of a data frame to which has specific headers. Eg "01-01" to select January data.

But while finding the average by piping it through, I am running into an error.

The code I wrote was this.

```
Book1 <- read_excel("X:/X/X/X- X/X/Book1.xlsx",sheet = "Sheet7")

Jan_Average <- Book1 %>% 
  select(`Row Labels`,contains("01-01")) %>% 
  mutate(Avg = rowMeans(Jan_Average[,2:5]))
```

But if I run this code till `select(Row Labels,contains("01-01"))` and then run the entire code, it works. I understand this is because when I run it till `select(Row Labels,contains("01-01"))` this creates a data frame and thus when we run the next line as well. The function is able to perform the average function as expected.

Is there a work around this situation. Shouldn't the pipe function create the Data frame from the first pipe function itself. And shouldn't this work?

The data frame I am working with is given below:

```
structure(list(`Row Labels` = c("X1", "X2", "X3", "X4"), `2019-01-01` = c(37, 
36, 45, 53), `2019-02-01` = c(3, 19, 14, 46), `2019-03-01` = c(28, 
2, 28, 28), `2019-04-01` = c(48, 70, 18, 16), `2019-05-01` = c(83, 
71, 58, 26), `2019-06-01` = c(85, 28, 83, 46), `2019-07-01` = c(60, 
20, 12, 77), `2019-08-01` = c(44, 66, 30, 99), `2019-09-01` = c(21, 
14, 31, 21), `2019-10-01` = c(26, 72, 72, 16), `2019-11-01` = c(15, 
96, 23, 100), `2019-12-01` = c(65, 0, 98, 66), `2020-01-01` = c(14, 
90, 45, 28), `2020-02-01` = c(62, 6, 47, 81), `2020-03-01` = c(18, 
40, 55, 10), `2020-04-01` = c(17, 9, 98, 54), `2020-05-01` = c(87, 
26, 56, 66), `2020-06-01` = c(50, 63, 82, 17), `2020-07-01` = c(49, 
48, 50, 21), `2020-08-01` = c(0, 92, 66, 16), `2020-09-01` = c(14, 
60, 61, 79), `2020-10-01` = c(60, 74, 58, 5), `2020-11-01` = c(90, 
80, 57, 12), `2020-12-01` = c(21, 70, 28, 55), `2021-01-01` = c(39, 
21, 17, 61), `2021-02-01` = c(11, 97, 48, 43), `2021-03-01` = c(59, 
50, 31, 14), `2021-04-01` = c(36, 88, 50, 4), `2021-05-01` = c(37, 
85, 79, 66), `2021-06-01` = c(27, 7, 75, 2), `2021-07-01` = c(20, 
51, 6, 67), `2021-08-01` = c(5, 54, 47, 55), `2021-09-01` = c(73, 
59, 1, 23), `2021-10-01` = c(32, 0, 50, 24), `2021-11-01` = c(17, 
36, 18, 16), `2021-12-01` = c(47, 70, 72, 23), `2022-01-01` = c(100, 
47, 18, 57), `2022-02-01` = c(27, 8, 30, 67), `2022-03-01` = c(19, 
72, 72, 86), `2022-04-01` = c(93, 39, 7, 42), `2022-05-01` = c(55, 
66, 18, 99), `2022-06-01` = c(77, 80, 86, 11), `2022-07-01` = c(1, 
71, 88, 9), `2022-08-01` = c(54, 55, 25, 66), `2022-09-01` = c(15, 
13, 51, 19), `2022-10-01` = c(28, 29, 23, 83), `2022-11-01` = c(96, 
25, 63, 99), `2022-12-01` = c(16, 95, 47, 9)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

The error I am getting is:

[image]

Is there a way to get the average of the selected data "01-01" using the pipe function? Can someone tell me what is wrong and what would be the correct work around with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Jan_Average` is not instantiated until *after* the entire pipeline completes, so you won't be able to do what you want.

Even further, (almost) "never" include the frame name in a pipe on its data, it's better (when using tidyverse) to consider that in a `mutate`, the data is the result of all of the verbs before it, not as the data was when the pipe started. Sometimes it might be the same, but anytime there's something that reduces filters (`select`), rows (`filter`), order of rows (`arrange`), or the values within (`mutate`, `summarize`, `reframe`), the original data and the data as-seen at that moment are likely two different things.

In the tidyverse nomenclature, you can start to do what you want using `cur_data()`:

```r
Book1 %>%
  select(`Row Labels`,contains("01-01")) %>%
  mutate(Avg = rowMeans(cur_data()[,2:5])) 
# # A tibble: 4 × 6
#   `Row Labels` `2019-01-01` `2020-01-01` `2021-01-01` `2022-01-01`   Avg
#   <chr>               <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 X1                     37           14           39          100  47.5
# 2 X2                     36           90           21           47  48.5
# 3 X3                     45           45           17           18  31.2
# 4 X4                     53           28           61           57  49.8
```

But the preferred method is likely to use `pick`, which can take integers (column indices) or names:

```r
Book1 %>%
  select(`Row Labels`,contains("01-01")) %>%
  mutate(Avg = rowMeans(pick(2:5)))
# # A tibble: 4 × 6
#   `Row Labels` `2019-01-01` `2020-01-01` `2021-01-01` `2022-01-01`   Avg
#   <chr>               <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 X1                     37           14           39          100  47.5
# 2 X2                     36           90           21           47  48.5
# 3 X3                     45           45           17           18  31.2
# 4 X4                     53           28           61           57  49.8
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation. This is very helpful. I had a few questions, what does `cur_data()` do here? Also will `pick()` also have the same issue as its giving column indices of a data frame which is not yet made since you mentioned that the DF is only created is the pipe function is completed. So how does providing the reference for the index work as the DF itself wont be created.

Comment: Actually, in verifying things I just discovered that `cur_data()` is [deprecated](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/deprec-context.html) in favor of `pick()`. The intent of both (now primarily `pick`) is to provide the state of the data as it should be at that point in the chain. So if for instance `Book1` has 100 rows, then when you do `Book1 %>% select(\`Row Labels\`,contains("01-01")) %>%
slice_head(n=5) %>% mutate(Avg = rowMeans(pick(2:5)))`, the `pick()` will only "see" rows 1-5, which is the data as of that point in the pipe. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yeah. `cur_data()` is deprecated for `pick()`, I noticed it when I ran the code. And the rest of the things makes absolute sense. `pick()` basically provides the reference of the DF while including all the transformational functions which has been passed through `%>%` function. And returns the result based on that. Understood. Thank you so much for the explanation. Learned something new today.

Comment: Does `pick()` index start from 0, because I was writing the same code using `pick()` statement even though the columns are 14, it says `ℹ Location 14 doesn't exist.
ℹ There are only 13 columns`. Do you know why?

Comment: When using integer-indexing with `pick`, it is 1-based (as with almost all things R). Realize that the number of columns that `pick` "sees" is based on the data "at the moment" after all of the verbs imposed in the current pipe. For example, `mtcars` has 11 columns; with, `mtcars %>% select(1:6) %>% mutate(a = pick(..))`, the `pick(..)` can choose up to 6 columns, regardless of the fact that the _origin_ of the dplyr pipe started with 11 columns. Is that what you're seeing?

Comment: Yup. I kept that in mind. So in order to avoid the confusion. I normally pipe the function till the pick statement is run. And see the DF and then run used the `pick()` function so that I can clearly see the columns present. Unfortunately. Here I have two columns in the start which are character and 12 columns which the year `2019` which are all `int` type. So I have 14 columns and used this statement `mutate(Sum2019 = rowSums(pick(3:14)))` but the above mentioned error came up. Which confuses me since the there are 14 columns in the DF

Comment: For simplicity, it might be easier to _deselect_ columns you know you have vice selecting them. For instance, each of these work with the code in my answer: `rowMeans(pick(-1))` and `rowMeans(pick(-\`Row Labels\`))` and `pick(-any_of("Row Labels"))`. The `pick` function enjoys the full tidy-select ecosystem that one might use in other dplyr verbs.

Comment: Can we give the column names here instead of deselecting the column which cant be computed. Like any way we could write the same mutate statement and give column names as range. Like we use in select statements? `select(Row Labels, X1)` like this?

The funny part is if I use this statement `mutate(Sum2019 = rowSums(pick(3:13)))` using even though the last column in the index `14`, it gives the sum of all the columns as expected.

Comment: As I said ... `pick` can use all of the tidy-select methods. You can do _exactly that_. You can even do `pick(\`2019-01-01\`:\`2022-01-01\`)` for a range of columns. So I think anything you can do in `select` you can also do in `pick` ... I haven't found where it fails, so ... try it!

Comment: Yeah it worked. I used `any_of()` and it worked. I feel giving column names is always better than using index numbers. Also I had a question, When we use `mutate` to create a new column and then in the next line of piping can we use that newly created new column name in another `mutate` statement for mathematical calculation or an `select` statement.?

Comment: With `dplyr::mutate`, when you create a new column, you can reference it in the _same_ `mutate` call (e.g., `mutate(newcol = 1 + oldcol, newcol = newcol * 2)` and in all subsequent verbs in the current pipe.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253999/discussion-between-user20203146-and-r2evans).